# Solving $5\sin x=1+2\cos^2x$, without sketching a graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$5\sin x=1+2\cos^2x$$
"Solve, for $0 \le x <360$" I know using rearrangement $x= 30°$.

I also know using a graph sketch and knowledge of symmetry that the other solutions within the range can be derived; however, I'm under the impression that there's an algebraic way of concluding the solutions. I Recall my teacher somehow doing so but I dont remember how... Is the fastest way really to sketch out the $\sin$ graph and then visually work out the other solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to start with the fact that $\sin x=\frac 1 2$ since you told me you knew that in the comments. Once you have that, using a calculator, you should get $\sin^{-1} \frac 1 2=30^\circ$. Now, you know that $\sin(180^\circ-x)=\sin x$, so you also have the answer $180^\circ-30^\circ=150^\circ$. Again, no graphing required, but you still have to use an identity of $\sin(180^\circ-x)=\sin x$.

For $\cos x$, this identity is $\cos x=\cos -x=\cos(360^\circ-x)$. For $\tan x$, it is $\tan x=\tan(x+180^\circ)$. Using these identities, you can generate answers other than what your calculator gives you without graphing.

Comment: That's what I did to get the value of 30°... $ x =sin^{-1}(\frac{1}{2},-3)$ therefore $x=30$

Comment: $\sin x=\frac 1 2$. Thus, you have two answers: $30^\circ$ and $150^\circ$. Was your question how to get $150^\circ$?

Comment: But the calculator will give the principle value, closest to the origin..

Comment: Yes, without sketching the graph

Comment: I already knew the values for $x$, my question was can I find the other values without sketching graph...

Comment: @James Please see my edited answer above. I think it will help you.

Comment: @James Just remember that if $\alpha$ is a solution of $\sin x=k$, then also $180^\circ-\alpha$ is a solution.

Comment: If the values go into the next period, then you have to use the $x=x-360^\circ$ angle. However, as I showed with $180^\circ-30^\circ=150^\circ$, the answer that these identities give you is a different angle. For example, if we have $\cos x=\frac 1 2$, we get $x=60^\circ$ from our calculator and then use $\cos x=\cos(360^\circ-x)$ to get $360^\circ-60^\circ=300^\circ$, which is, again, a different angle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I now remembers my ASTC acronym for recalling functions and their positive quadrants

Comment: @James No, $\cos(270^\circ-x)=-\sin x$. Also, glad I could help!

Comment: This has so far saved me so much time and helps [i] so [/i] much with understanding whats going on. The rest of the class still draw curves where they constantly need to manipulate the scales ect. I can now quickly go from $ 0\le x\le 360, acos(x+b)= \theta$ to $x=((cos^{-1} \frac{\theta}{a}, or, 360-cos^{-1}  \frac{\theta}{a})\pm 360k)-b$ and similarly with $sinx$, $tanx$ almost seems too easy due to its interval of $180^\circ$

Comment: @James I'm really glad I was able to help you! Most of my friends still use the graphing method, so I'm glad someone was able to appreciate the formula method.

Answer (score 2):

The well known identity: cos^2(x)=1-sin^2(x),

and the problem: 5sin(x)-1-2cos^2(x)=0,

lead to: 5sin(x)-1-2(1-sin^2(x)).

In other words (call sin(x) as Z): 5Z-1-2(1-Z^2)=0

This is a second degree equation. Apply the well known formula to solve.

Solve for Z, and the set x=arcsin(Z) to get the answerS.
    Recall that sin(x)->z means arcsin(z)->x. Arcus functions are the inverses.

Finally apply the degree limitation (0<=d<360) to choose the correct branch (closest to zero).

Comment: This explains how to solve the question, this does not answer the question at all

Comment: Oh. Misunderstood the question. You are absolutely right :)

Comment: @James How does this not address the OP statement "however, I'm under the impression that there's an algebraic way of concluding the solutions. I Recall my teacher somehow doing so but I don't remember how?"

Comment: @Dr. MV The question is, How do i solve the second solution for $x$, the non-principle-value that a calculator will give. Not "How do I solve this equation" He doesn't explain how to find the second solution; just says "Finally apply the degree limitation (0<=d<360) to choose the correct branch (closest to zero)." What does that even mean?

Comment: @james Nowhere in the OP is there any reference to any of items in your assertion.  None.  The OP is requesting an algebraic solution only.

Comment: I don't know if you're pedantically backing up "R.s" due to their some-what adherence to math.stackexchange rules but just think about the situation logically: Somebody comes up to you in person and says "I've found the first solution to this question, how do I find the second, I don't want to sketch a graph" You don't respond "Here's how to solve the question - just as you've done - now apply the degree limitation. I'm not even going to tell you what the answer is or how to find it, just apply the degree limitation.

Answer (score 1):

By the identity $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$, which holds for all $x$, your equation becomes
$$5\sin x=1+2(1-\sin^2x).$$
Rearranging the terms shows that this has the same solutions as
$$2\sin^2x+5\sin x-3=0.$$
This is a quadratic equation in $\sin x$, so the quadratic formula tells us that
$$\sin x=\frac{-5\pm\sqrt{5^2-4\cdot2\cdot(-3)}}{2\cdot 2}=\frac{5\pm\sqrt{49}}{4},$$
so either $\sin x=\tfrac12$ or $\sin x=-3$. Of course the latter is impossible as $\sin x$ takes values from $-1$ to $1$, so $\sin x=\tfrac12$. In high school I was forced to learn by heart that then
$$x=30^{\circ}\qquad\text{ or }\qquad x=150^{\circ},$$
but I'm sure you have your own way of solving this.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, I knew how to solve the first solution, the question was how to find the second conveniently. Saying "In high school I was forced to learn by heart that then $x=150^\circ$" doesn't help.

Comment: Fair enough, I misunderstood your question as asking for a way to solve the problem as a whole. I'll leave it up for reference though.